# AWS facade in Laravel fails to instantiate CloudSearch class properly

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services

I am using the AWS facade for Laravel and I can instantiate a CloudSearchDomainClient object like this:

```
$c = AWS::createClient('cloudsearchdomain', ['endpoint' => '{our-endpoint}']);
```

But when I attempt to search like so:

```
$c->search(['query' => 'test']);
```

I get this error: `Aws\CloudSearchDomain\Exception\CloudSearchDomainException with message 'Error executing "Search" on "2013-01-01/search"; AWS HTTP error: cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: 2013-01-01`

It thinks the version is the endpoint.

I have the proper .env vars, eg. AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY and AWS_DEFAULT_REGION. I am able to use other AWS services, but CloudSearch specifically is a problem. What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Just try to provide a correct `endpoint` value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are mixing two things. An endpoint is a domain and api version is a date. So it should be more like this:

```
$c = AWS::createClient(
    'cloudsearchdomain',
    [
        'endpoint' => 'https://example.com',
        'apiVersion' => '2013-01-01',
    ]
);
```

Comment: The problem was as simple as a missing https:// at the beginning.